# callback to function after .each() has completed?

Tags: jquery, each

Not sure if this is possible or how to go about it. I am using the following in an $.ajax response which works perfectly fine, however, I need to call the function `loadSlider();` AFTER the loop is finished iterating.

```
if (response.success)
{
    $.each( response.screenshots, function( index, value ) {
        //add the slide
        $( '#slider1' ).prepend( '<li data-id="'+value.screenshot_id+'"><img src="/showimage.php?show='+value.image_filename+'" alt=""></li>' );
        //add the pager
        $( '#rslides-pager' ).prepend( '<li><a href="javascript:;"># here</a></li>' );
    });

    //want to call loadSlider(); AFTER everything above is completed                        
}
```

Comment: so you can call after each closing ``)}``

Comment: Whats the problem? You can call it.

Comment: It is ajax - won't this happen asynchronously, therefore, before the each has completed?

Comment: i dont see any ajax here

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`$.each()` iterates over the array synchronously, so you can simply run your code after the `$.each();` call.

```
if (response.success) {
    $.each( response.screenshots, function( index, value ) {
        // do stuff
    });

    loadSlider();
}
```

As you mention AJAX: Only the actual success callback (i.e. the function that most likely contains the code you posted) is executed asynchronously. Any code inside that function runs synchronously (unless you call another asynchronous function in there of course).

Comment: Did not know that... didn't even think to try because I assumed async.  Thanks!

Comment: Lol same happened with me... Thanks you already asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

jquery has a jQuery.when(), this provides a way to execute callback functions based on zero or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

[jquery $.when reference](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Now in your code maybe:

```
if (response.success) {
    var iterate = $.each( response.screenshots, function( index, value ) {
        // do stuff
    });

   $.when(iterate)
    .then(  loadSlider, myFailure );

}
```

The first function is on success callback and the other function is on fail callback.

Answer (score -1):

You can launch slider in the last iteration, it's easy:

```
if(response.success)
{
    var count = response.screenshots.length;
    $.each(response.screenshots, function (index, value) {
        //add the slide
        $('#slider1').prepend('<li data-id="' + value.screenshot_id + '"><img src="/showimage.php?show=' + value.image_filename + '" alt=""></li>');
        //add the pager
        $('#rslides-pager').prepend('<li><a href="javascript:;"># here</a></li>');
        if (!--count) {
            //want to call loadslider(); after everything above is completed                        
            loadslider();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$.each( response.screenshots, function( index, value ) {

    }).promise().done(function () {
            //Completed
});
```

Sample :

```
if (response.success)
{
    $.each( response.screenshots, function( index, value ) {
        //add the slide
        $( '#slider1' ).prepend( '<li data-id="'+value.screenshot_id+'"><img src="/showimage.php?show='+value.image_filename+'" alt=""></li>' );
        //add the pager
        $( '#rslides-pager' ).prepend( '<li><a href="javascript:;"># here</a></li>' );
    }).promise().done(function () {
            //Completed
        });


}
```

Comment: The promise chain method is not working with $.each.